# ListView ItemClick not working in Xamarin.Forms (iOS)

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

We have a custom `ListView` which has an `ItemClickCommand` property. We are binding this in a XAML file using the `local` keyword. It's working fine for Xamarin.Forms Android, but its not clickable in Xamarin.forms iOS.

Please suggest how to proceed or what we are doing wrong in code.

Code is written below:

XAML file:

```
<StackLayout x:Class="XYZ"
         xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:XYZ.UI;assembly=XYZ">

            <local:ListView ItemClickCommand="{Binding OnDataSelectionCommand, Mode=TwoWay}" ItemsSource="{Binding DataList}">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>

                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Label FontSize="17"
                                       HorizontalOptions="Start"
                                       Text="{Binding }"
                                       TextColor="Black"
                                       VerticalOptions="Center" />


                                <Label FontSize="17"
                                       HorizontalOptions="Start"
                                       Text=" , "
                                       TextColor="Black"
                                       VerticalOptions="Center" />


                            </StackLayout>
                        </ViewCell>

                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </local:ListView>
```

View Model :

```
private Command _onDataSelectionCommand;
public Command OnDataSelectionCommand
{
      get
      {
           return _onDataSelectionCommand ?? (_onDataSelectionCommand = new Command(async (s) =>
           {
                // TODO: get selected item from list !!
           }));
       }
}
```

Custom List Created :

```
  using System.Windows.Input;
  using Xamarin.Forms;         
  namespace XYZ.UI
  {     

    public class ListView : Xamarin.Forms.ListView
   {
    public static BindableProperty ItemClickCommandProperty = BindableProperty.Create<ListView, ICommand>(x => x.ItemClickCommand, null);

    public ListView()
    {
        this.ItemTapped += this.OnItemTapped;
    }

    public ICommand ItemClickCommand
    {
        get { return (ICommand)this.GetValue(ItemClickCommandProperty); }
        set { this.SetValue(ItemClickCommandProperty, value); }
    }

    private void OnItemTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item != null && this.ItemClickCommand != null && this.ItemClickCommand.CanExecute(e))
        {
            this.ItemClickCommand.Execute(e.Item);
        }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the [SelectedItem](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Xamarin.Forms.ListView.SelectedItem/) property of ListView to Bind. This will give you the object (item) of the collection you bound to the list.

Sample project can be found [here](https://github.com/rohitvipin/XamarinForms_Dynamic_ListView_Item).

Also please note that [ItemTapped](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/event/Xamarin.Forms.ListView.ItemTapped/) is not same as [ItemSelected](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/event/Xamarin.Forms.ListView.ItemSelected/).

If you are interested in Binding a Command to ListView Item Tapped then please have a look at this forum post about the same - [How to bind a Command to ListView.ItemTapped](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/60937/how-to-bind-a-command-to-listview-itemtapped).

Comment: Thanks for Answer, for IOS click is working but after long press

Comment: Long press on the list item?

Comment: Yeah, we have a List View , the above code is working fine and we are able to select the item from ListView. But in case of iOS, we need to long press the item to get event fired.

Comment: Does your `OnItemTapped` fire on tap of list item?

Comment: Yes, it fired when clicked in both the cases (android and iOS) but in iOS to fire it we need to press it for long time (long press).

Comment: The event works same way in both iOS and Android. Also note that there is no long press event support in Xamarin.Forms.

Comment: @PoojaRawat We have the same problem. Did you find a way to solve it?

Comment: When multiple GestureRecognizers are registered iOS seems to favor the last one and Android calls them all. This led to the problem in my case.

Comment: Its always better to register only one event handler and call as many functions as you want from it. @Amenti